# AWS Certificate Manager - SSL says in use but HTTPS does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-certificate-manager

So here is my issue. I have a Rails 5 Application that is being deployed to AWS using Elastic Beanstalk. I purchased the domain name (eightysixpad.me) from Bluehost.com and updated the DNS records to point to the IP address of the EC2 instance that was created.

I used AWS's Certificate Manager to create an SSL certificate for the domain eightysixpad.me and www.eightysixpad.me. I have verified both of them through email. I created a Load Balancer under the Elastic Beanstalk environment and applied the SSL certificate to it. The AWS Certificate Manager console says the SSL certificate is in use; however, when I go to https://eightysixpad.me, it says Site Cannot be reached. http://eightysixpad.me works fine but says it is unsecure.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong! Any help would be greatly appreciate and I would be more than happy to provide more information if necessary!

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: You should point the domain to the LB not the EC2.

Answer (score 0):

Update the DNS entry to a CNAME and make it point to the DNS endpoint of the ELB , to which you have added the EC2 instance(s).

For example create new CNAME entry to ELB Dns endpoint "name-of-elb-unique-.ap-southeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com"

ELBs in AWS do not have an IP address (always dns names) as IP address keep changing

Comment: Thank You both for your help! I am a total newb one it comes to this DevOps stuff :/ I currently have a CNAME for www that points to eightysixpad.me. Should I change that to point to the EC2 instance?

Comment: Perfect! Got everything working! Thank You very much!